# Вложенная группировка в TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

Только начал осваивать привязку данных в wpf, не могу понять как сделать вложенную группировку данных в treeview.

Имеется класс

```
public class Track
{
  public int year {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public string Category {get;set}
}
```

Хочу отобразить в treeview с группировкой:

```
+---2010
|   +---Rap
|   |       Track 1
|   |       Track 2
|   |       
|   \---Rock
|           Track 5
|           Track 6
|           
+---2011
    +---Rap
    |       Track 7
    |       Track 10
    |       
    \---Rock
            Track 11
```

В коде создаю наблюдаемую коллекцию `ObservableCollection<Track> items = new ObservableCollection<Track>()` и заполняю её. Потом указываю источник данных для treeview:  treeview.ItemsSource=items;

Дальше, на сколько я понял, мне нужно HierarchicalDataTemplate. Но я не могу сделать их вложенными.

Сейчас я вручную создаю TreeViewItem с годом, к нему добавляю дочерний с категорией, а к ней уже название трека. Понимаю что это не правильно, вот и хочу понять как можно сгруппировать с помощью xaml.

Comment: Вроде бы вы всё делаете правильно. А покажите ваш `HierarchicalDataTemplate`.

Comment: @VladD Сейчас мой код не работает. Пытаюсь сначала научиться хоть как-нибудь группировать данные http://pastebin.com/H5mAwnNR .  Думаю если пойму,то смысл будет примерно такой: есть 2 collectionviewsource, к одному привязываем коллекцию items и он сгруппирует по годам; во второй привязываем результат первого и группирует по категориям.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас иерархическая структура данных или к коей вы приведете в будущем, например к такой:

```
public class Track
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //---
}
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Track> Tracks { get; set; }
    //----
}

public class Album
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    //----
}

public ObservableCollection<Album> Albums {get; set;}
```

то делается это следующим образом:

Начнем делать шаблон дерева с нижнего уровня. 
Итак, на нижнем уровне находится название трека, так как по условию он не имеет дочерних элементов, то определяем простой шаблон `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="trackTemplate">        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />       
</DataTemplate>
```

Дальше поднимаемся на один уровень вверх и определяем шаблон для категории. Тут уже есть дочерние элементы, поэтому определяем `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, а в `ItemTemplate` указываем определенный прежде шаблон:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="categoryTemplate"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource trackTemplate}" <!--здесь указывается шаблон для дочерних элементов -->
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Tracks}">        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Еще на уровень вверх, самый верхний уровень с годом. В `ItemTemplate` указываем шаблон `categoryTemplate`

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="yearsTemplate"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource categoryTemplate}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Сategories}">        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

При объявлении дерева нужно указать шаблон всего для одного уровня, для самого верхнего.

```
<TreeView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource yearsTemplate}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Albums}"/>
```

Comment: большое спасибо! Правильно ли я понимаю, что по шаблонам лишь вытягиваются связанные данные? Те они определяют как будут отображаться коллекции внутри других классов?  И еще вопрос: а возможно ли так же группировать плоский список как у меня изначально?

Comment: @CrazyAlex25, шаблоны описывают то, как будут выглядеть объекты в представлении. Не понял что значит "вытягиваются".  Дерево разрастается благодаря тому что мы указываем ItemTemplate, который в свою очередь также является деревом. По поводу второго вопроса сказать не могу, думаю лучше изначально правильно спроектировать архитектуру.

Answer (score 0):

Приведен пример "конечной" иерархии. Когда заведомо  известно, сколько уровней вложенности имеет дерево. Как поступить n уровнем вложенности?

```
class A
{
   UInt64 ID {get;set;}
   UInt64 ParentID {get;set}
   string Description {get;set}
} 

ObservableCollection<A>
```

`ID` - идентификатор записи, `ParentID` - ссылка на `ID` родителя. У веток верхнего уровня, соответственно, `ParentID = 0`. Уровней вложенности может быть, сколько угодно. Например, любой произвольный классификатор чего-либо.....