# Список внутри списка в WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь реализовать список внутри списка, что-то типа такого(одного уровня вложенности мне хватит):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочется отметить, что сам список заполняется по нажатию кнопки. С помощью ListBox так и не получилось, через bind(делаю программно через ItemSource) удается только один корневой уровень. На XAML выглядит так:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listObjects" Margin="10,10,779,133" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightSteelBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="brd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                            <CheckBox Focusable="False" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </CheckBox>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen"/>
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Соответственно один уровень добавляется условно так(не буду вдаваться в подробности заполнения списка):

```
private void Load_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var list = new List<string>();
    ls.Add("qwerty");
    ls.Add("asdfgh");
    listObjects.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Вопрос, собственно, заключается в том, как реализовать многоуровневый список с привязкой к коллекциям. Готов разобраться и переписать заново, если поможете своим кодом и т.п.

Comment: Просто переопределите ItemTemplate и в DataTemplate используйте ещё один ItemsControl

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно всё же как-то более подробно, если несложно, то со вставками кода(или может ссылками на примеры и т.п.). кому-то просто, для кого-то пока что нет)) подробнее я имею ввиду не про Template-ы, а как задать такой шаблон.

Comment: на скриншоте у вас TreeView, как сделать см. тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584996/%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-treeview-wpf/585431#585431

Answer (score 6, accepted):

И так, для реализации данной задачи нам следует сначала обзавестись неким классом, который мы укажем нашему приложения как некий источник данных для привязки (`DataContext`), пусть на данный момент это будет пустой класс с названием `MyDataClass`:

```
public class MyDataClass
{

}
```

Хорошо. Далее нам надо создать простейший класс для одного элемента в нашем списке. Пусть он содержит некую `string` переменную с именем `Name` и некую коллекцию `List<string>` с именем `Films`. Сам класс назовем `Category`:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Films { get; set; }
}
```

Хорошо! Теперь можно создать в ранее созданном классе `MyDataClass` пустую (на данный момент) `ObservableCollection<>`. Назовем ее `MyCategory` и пусть она изначально инициализируется. Наш класс станет таким:

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public ObservableCollection<Category> MyCategory { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
}
```

Ок, пол пути пройдено, осталось дизайн элементов и все это связать. Давайте для начала свяжем! В `MainWindow` в самом начале создадим наш `MyDataClass`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private MyDataClass MyData;
}
```

Затем после `InitializeComponent();` нам нужно этот класс инициализировать и задать как `DataContext`. Также давайте сразу и заполним все это некими данными для теста:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MyData = new MyDataClass();
    DataContext = MyData;

    MyData.MyCategory.Add(new Category
    {
        Name = "Боевики",
        Films = new List<string> { "Фильм 1", "Фильм 2", "Фильм 3" }
    });

    MyData.MyCategory.Add(new Category
    {
        Name = "Комедии",
        Films = new List<string> { "Фильм 1", "Фильм 2", "Фильм 3" }
    });
}
```

Ну, уже почти финиш. Осталось создать элемент отображения. В `WPF` считай каждый элемент может содержать в себе кучу других (к примеру мы можем в кнопку засунуть картинку, текст или что нибудь еще). В нашем случае мы можем переопределить шаблон элемента у `ListBox` на тот, который содержал бы в себе текстовое поле и еще один `ListBox`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyCategory}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Films}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Заметьте, я выше уже указал данные для привязки, а именно:

- У основного `ListBox` указал `ItemsSource="{Binding MyCategory}"`, что связало его с данными в нашей коллекции `MyCategory`
- `TextBlock` - ему указал место, от куда он должен брать текст `Text="{Binding Name}"`. То есть привязанная коллекция `MyCategory` содержит в себе элементы типа `Category` (наша созданная коллекция для одного элемента), вот там мы указывали `Name` и к нему в итоге и привязались.
- Внутренний `ListBox` - ну тут уже ясно, мы ему указали данные к нашему списку `Films`.

Ну что, давайте запустим. Результат должен быть следующим:

[image: result]

---

Если вы перейдете все же на `Binding`, то в данному случае при изменение в коллекции каких либо элементов у вас скорей всего не обновятся данные визуально. Многих это пугает (лично у меня многих знакомых этот факт отталкивает от `Binding`'a.) По этому напишу сразу как бороться! Тут все просто, нужно реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` там, где что то может измениться. В нашем случае, это класс `Category`. Допишем в него пару строк:

```
public class Category: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string> Films { get; set; }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Теперь нам осталось переписать то, что может обновится, например имя:

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get => name;
    set
    {
        name = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Name");
    }
}
```

Вот и все, теперь наш интерфейс будет обновлять поле "Имя" (Name) в соответствие с изменениями в коллекции `MyCategory`. Для списков лучше использовать `ObservableCollection` так, как она умеет оповещать об изменение данных.

---

То, что вам надо - это всего лишь пример того, как разместить `ListBox` внутри другого `ListBox`, но я посчитал, что вам будет полезно узнать, как в итоге все данные привязать и как этим пользоваться, ведь это основы и самый "сок" `WPF`. Пытался как можно подробней все расписать для наглядности. Надеюсь помог. Удачи!

Comment: "...многих знакомых этот факт отталкивает от Binding'a ...напишу сразу как бороться...". C байдингом не надо бороться, с байдингом нужно работать, уметь работать. Если вы пишете `OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName ...`, то вот так `OnPropertyChanged("Name");` писать не надо. Вот этот атрибут `[CallerMemberName]` заставляет компилятор самому определить название свойства и подставить его в вызов метода, потому достаточно написать так  `OnPropertyChanged();` .

Comment: @EvgeniyZ благодарю за подробные пояснения, в этом разобрался. вопрос, как сделать связь между внешним listbox'ом и внутренним? ну, например, при выделении "боевики", чтобы выбирались все фильмы из этого раздела. после winforms на wpf приходится перестраивать мышление, конечно...

Comment: @PavelNewSky лучше используйте стандартный TreeView а не изобретайте велосипед без надобности.

Comment: @FoggyFinder я почти для своих целей всё отработал, осталось только понять, как при выделении, как в примере, "боевики", выделялось всё внутри. а в TreeView нужно тоже разбираться, как туда чекбоксы вставить, как сделать множественный выбор и т.д.

Comment: @PavelNewSky зависит от того как вы организовали ваши типы данных

Comment: @FoggyFinder давайте разговаривать в рамках данного ответа. предположим, что у нас есть проект, созданный из кода, скопированного из ответа Евгения.

Comment: @PavelNewSky не получится, нужно вместо `string` перейти к типу данных который будет отвечать за фильм с возможностью выбора. То есть `type Film = { Name : string; IsSelected : bool}`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74436/discussion-between-pavelnewsky-and-foggy-finder).

Comment: @Bulson Это все понятно, здесь я указал для наглядности, не более. Дальше если человеку нужно, то сам разберётся и сама студия ему тоже должна в этом плане помочь.

Answer (score 4):

Если в ходе обдумывания интерфейса представляется многоуровневый список с одним уровнем вложенности, то вероятно здесь стоит остановится и задуматься над тем, что, возможно, вам всего-лишь нужно сгруппировать данные по определенному ключу.

Для группировки удобно использовать стандартные средства (`CollectionViewSource`).

Например, вы хотите сгруппировать данные по свойству жанр (`Genre`):

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding Data}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Genre" />
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>
```

где `Data` - список ваших объектов.

В `ListView` шаблон заголовка задается в `GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate`

```
<ListView.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
```

Простой пример реализации такого подхода по [ссылке](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)