# Размещение элементов в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется некоторый набор Фактов(Заголовок, Текст). Пользователь может его дополнять. Мне нужно разместить на Grid все эти факты. Проблема в том, что не получается вычислить размер блока с текстом для его позиционирования. В итоге всё смещается.

```
    void LoadFacts(int FactId)
    {
        grid.Children.Clear();
        double indent = 0;
        foreach (Fact fact in facts)
        {
            Label title = new Label()
            {
                Content = fact.Title,
                Margin = new Thickness(30, indent, 0, 0),
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                FontSize = 20,
            };

            TextBlock text = new TextBlock()
            {
                Text = fact.Text,
                Margin = new Thickness(30, 50 + indent, 0, 0),
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                FontSize = 16,
                TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
                Background = Brushes.AliceBlue,
            };

            text.Measure(new Size(Double.PositiveInfinity, Double.PositiveInfinity));
            indent += text.DesiredSize.Height;

            grid.Children.Add(title);
            grid.Children.Add(text);
        }

        grid.Height = indent;
    }
```

[image: Результат]

Comment: А вам не кажется, что в великом WPF, у которого есть классный язык разметки, XAML - размещать объекты через код - это кощунство и изврат?

Comment: Заранее нельзя предугадать количество и содержание фактов

Comment: Для этого существуют такие вещи, как `Binding` и элементы типа `ListBox` со своим стилем

Comment: А почему всё таки DesiredSize не работает как нужно?

Comment: Для отчетов и документов есть специальные инструменты, но насколько мне известно они только на просмотр работают. Уточните что вы имеете ввиду под "Пользователь может его дополнять."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

То, что вы пишите - я считаю извращением! Во первых - WPF без `MVVM`, привязок и прочих их элементов, это как холодильник без мотора на морозе, вроде морозит, но не так, как может... Во вторых - по правилам `MVVM` ваш код не должен знать, что у него открыто окно, в окне есть `Lable` или ещё какие то вещи, не правильно это.

Как это правильно сделать:

- Реализуйте грамотный `Binding`, как это сделать - примеров много, можете мой недавний [ответ посмотреть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797321/220553).
- Далее вам нужно определиться что именно вы хотите видеть на странице. Это можно реализовать к примеру с помощью `ListBox`, а можно с помощью `ItemsControl`. Возьмём к примеру `ItemsControl`, сааамый простейший:

  ```
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <Label Content="{Binding}" />
          </DataTemplate>
      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ItemsControl>
  ```

Что мы тут видим? У нас есть сам `ItemsControl`, который с помощью `ItemsSource` привязывается к некой коллекции `MyCollection` (о ней позже), внутри мы переопределяем шаблон и задаём для теста обычный `Lable`, который привязан к значению в коллекции `MyCollection` (тут на самом деле может быть совеошенно любой шаблон, который вы пожелаете, будь то шапка, текст, автор и др. параметры).

Все, остаётся нам добавить коллекцию и с ней работать:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> MyCollection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();
```

Ну и добавляем в нее:

```
MyCollection.Add("hello");
MyCollection.Add("word!");
```

На выходе, если все сделали правильно, вы получите нечто подобное:

[image: Result]

Вот и все. Если пытаетесь что то написать, так пишите это правильно с самого начала, иначе потом будет ооочень много проблем. Удачи в освоение!

Comment: Большое спасибо. А если должна происходить смена страницы? Как это правильно реализовать?

Comment: @ВладОгого тут уж лучше задать отдельный вопрос на эту тему, я могу вам дать лишь логику того, как это примерно должно быть, но не код или чего то ещё. По логике у вас должна быть общая база всяких "постов" и одна привязанная коллекция (как в ответе), также у вас должна быть команда/команды перехода. Ну и по их нажатию вы в привязанную коллекцию добавляете скажем 10 элементов, пропуская 10 предыдущих (это к примеру будет 2-ая страница). Пропускать и брать нужное число - это `Skip(10).Take(10)` у коллекции. Но опять же, может есть решения и лучше, я с этим не сталкивался. Сказал как бы сделал я

Comment: @ВладОгого Но не в коем случае не делайте то, что вы делали в вопросе. Не издевайтесь над бедным `WPF`)