# Убрать выделение с листбокса

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Имеется вот такой listbox [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/aNKbYG5n).
Как сделать так чтобы при наведении и нажатии на него не выделялся Item (Синем цветом в моем случае). Если можно привести пример кода.

Comment: Используйте ItemsControl вместо ListBox

Comment: Добавить ясности для глупых можно? К сожалению после замены словил ошибку. System.InvalidOperationException: "Перед использованием свойства ItemsSource семейство Items должно быть пустым."

Comment: Вот вам список через [ItemsControl](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799373/220553)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListBox>
   <ListBox.Resources>
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
      <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />  
   </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Если у Вас достаточно новая версия .net:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent"/>
```

Точно не помню, но по-моему, Вы можете так же это сделать в настройках ListBox'а (Properties).