# Создание элемента в коде

Tags: c#, wpf

Как написать то же самое, только в коде?

xaml:

```
<ProgressBar Name="progbar"
             IsIndeterminate="False"
             Orientation="Horizontal"
             Height="30"
             Margin="46,392,10,10"
             Foreground="#FF1A94E8" />
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=progbar, Path=Value, StringFormat={}{0:0}%}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Margin="376,359,418,57"/>
```

Пробую так c#:

```
Duration duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
DoubleAnimation doubleanimation = new DoubleAnimation(100.0, duration);
progbar.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
ProgressBar progbar1 = new ProgressBar();
progbar1.Name = "prr1";
progbar1.IsIndeterminate = false;
progbar1.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
progbar1.Height = 30;
progbar1.BeginAnimation(ProgressBar.ValueProperty, doubleanimation);
progbar1.Margin = new Thickness(28, 10, 28, 392);
progbar1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
grid.Children.Add(progbar1);
TextBlock tb1 = new TextBlock();
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.ElementName = "prr1";
binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Value");
binding.StringFormat = "{}{0:0}%}";
tb1.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
tb1.Margin = new Thickness(0, 10, 0, 0);
tb1.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
tb1.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
//tb1.Text = "asdasdasfasd";
grid.Children.Add(tb1);
```

Но что-то не клеится (предположительно бинд не отрабатывает), если раскоментить предпоследнюю строку, то текст появляется.

Comment: Это выглядит странно: `binding.StringFormat = "{}{0:0}%}"`. Попробуйте `binding.StringFormat = "{0:0}%"`

Comment: А что вас побудило на то, что бы перенести создание элементов в код? Я пойму это в WinForm, но в WPF не одного проекта не встречал, где это необходимо, максимум люди из за незнания делают подобное.

Comment: Ну и если делать привязку в коде, то лучше уж через `Source` задать ссылку на источник, чем через `ElementName` действовать

Comment: @EvgeniyZ мне нужно вытянуть данные с xml файла и на основе них создать n-количество прогресс баров. Я могу как то по другому сделать? Буду рад ссылке.

Comment: @Андрей NOP спасибо, почитаю, учту и такой вариант

Comment: Используйте привязки и шаблоны, коллекции отлично выводятся с помощью `ItemsControl` (или его наследников)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц [Создание своего контрола и динамическое его размещение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/841206/220553); [Простейших вывод кнопок с привязыванием некоторых свойств](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820820/220553); [А вот недавний ответ о том, что требуется для минимального WPF приложения, там в роли примера динамическое создание текста с полем для ввода и кнопкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/852526/220553); [Еще пример с простейшим выводом текста построчно из коллекции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799373/220553).