# WPF - Привязка динамически созданных объектов друг к другу и логике приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

В приложении есть ряд методов для функционированния приложения, задача заключается в подвязке динамически созданных инструментов управления друг к другу, а так же к методам приложения. Что бы не быть многословным:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходное состояние. После введения 3 полей - есть возможность загрузить контент, который может варироваться от 0 до 1000 элементов.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: Как подвязать динамически создающиеся кнопки "Скачать" к текстову поля из лейбла слева (конкретно по уровню с кнопкой), а так же подвязать к функции?

Comment: Что значит динамически? Если у вас там ItemsControl с ItemTemplate, то какие проблемы? Просто укажите команду и параметр в шаблоне.

Comment: @АндрейNOP не знаю что это такое, сейчас буду гуглить

Comment: @Rifter Вы на вопрос то ответьте, что значит динамически, как вы это делаете? Стандартный путь простой - у вас должен быть класс, который содержит в себе 3 свойства (int ID/URL Address и ICommand DownloadCommand), в этом классе реализуется `DownloadCommand` и вешается на него логика загрузки. Далее вы делаете в главном классе, который задан как DataContext коллекцию, которая будет содержать ранее созданный класс, ну и привязываете эту коллекцию к ListBox/ItemControls, переопределяя стиль на тот, который вам нужен, кнопке привязываете `Command="{Binding DownloadCommand}"`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ через добавление элемента в каждый из StackPanel, которые находятся в разных колонках. Циклом Foreach создаю новые объекты под каждый объект загрузки

Comment: @Rifter Значит ваш подход в корне неверен. Вам надо что то на подобии [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799373/220553), только не `string`, а свой отдельный класс, ну и `DataContext` не забудьте указать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за совет, делал костыльным методом даже не осознавая, что есть такие инструменты

Comment: Вот, досконально разберите это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/615927/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP Очень помогли, спасибо