# Не работает Binding у StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Не работает Binding у StackPanel

xaml

```
<StackPanel  Orientation="Vertical" DataContext="{Binding  Path=ObservableCollection2, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

cs

```
private ObservableCollection<Border> ObservableCollection2_ = new ObservableCollection<Border>();

public ObservableCollection<Border> ObservableCollection2
{
    get
    {
        return ObservableCollection2_;
    }
    private set
    {
        if (value == ObservableCollection2_) return;
        ObservableCollection2_ = value;
    }
}

var image = new Image();
border.Child = image;

ObservableCollection2.Add(border);
```

Если сделать таким образом то будет работать, но это не bindig

StackPanel2.Children.Add(border);

Comment: А что вы ожидаете от этого, что по вашему должно произойти?

Comment: В StackPanel добавиться изображения внутри рамок

Comment: StackPanel не является ItemsControl

Comment: StackPanel - не работает с коллекциями и чем то подобным, она создана для того, что бы "группировать" контроллы, не более. Хотите вывести коллекцию, используйте `ItemsControl` или то, что его реализует (например `ListBox`). Посмотрите [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799373/220553) ответ.

Comment: У Border  нету свойства Content :     <Border Content="{Binding}" />