# Как динамически добававлять элементы в ListBox?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я получаю из окна ввода список данных(email:password), далее эти данные должны идти в другое, основное окно приложения в виде списка ListBox.
Это код XAML основного окна:

```
<ListBox Name="listBoxAccountList" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                 Grid.Row="2">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID}" />
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Mail}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код C# окна ввода:

```
public partial class NewAccount : Window
    {
        class Acc
        {
            public int ID { get; set; }
            public string Mail { get; set; }
        }
        class DataUser
        {
            public string Email { get; set; }
            public string Password { get; set; }
        }
        public NewAccount()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void SaveCreatedAccount(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            var AccountList = new Dictionary<int, DataUser>();
            int i = 1;
            
            string[] s = textBoxAccount.Text.Split(new String[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            List<Acc> items = new List<Acc>();
            foreach (string line in s)
            {
                string[] mp = line.Split(':');
                AccountList.Add(i, new DataUser { Email = mp[0], Password = mp[1] });
                Array.Clear(mp, 0, 2);
                i++;
            }
            foreach(var IdMail in AccountList)
            {
                items.Add(new Acc { ID = IdMail.Key, Mail = IdMail.Value.Email });
            }
            mainWindow.listBoxAccountList.ItemsSource = items;
        }
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это код C# основного окна:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window { 
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void AddNewAccount(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            NewAccount NewAccountWindow = new NewAccount();
            NewAccountWindow.Show();
        }
    }
```

Не понимаю, что я сделал не так. 2 окна - это 2 разных xaml файла. Мне кажется, что {Binding ID} не видит класс, в который подаются данные.
Это все должно выглядеть как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также мне необходимо добавить кнопки справа, как на фотографии выше. При нажатие на кнопку должен открываться браузер(как открывать браузер я знаю. Проблема состоит только в кнопке), и туда должны филиться данные(email:pas) из строчки, откуда была нажата кнопка.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Размещение элементов в WPF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/799353/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-wpf)

Comment: Ай, не то я вам кинул, ошибка у вас основная в другом: [Как использовать переменные одной формы в другой?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/835223/220553), ссылку выше тоже гляньте, ибо сейчас вы ерундой занимаетесь.

Comment: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}">` поизучайте, как можно сделать привязку данных с использованием `ObservableCollection<T>` и реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Примеров полно. Так же как минимум прочитайте, что такое MVVM, и зачем оно надо.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, прочитаю и попробую)