# Как добавить элемент на форму WPF во время выполнения программы?

Tags: c#, wpf

Пишу игру "Викториния" на C# WPF, где в одной из менюшек мне нужно прочитать названия всех файлов в определенной папке, и затем вывести кнопки с этими названиями файлов. С чтением файлов из папки проблем не возникло: для примера, все названия всех файлов я сохранил в массиве FileNames[].

Вопрос такой: как во время выполнения программы мне выводить рядом друг с другом(что бы получился список) кнопки или любые другие элементы? Причем, все кнопки должны иметь одинаковые Hight, Width и т.п.
Каждая кнопка отличается ТОЛЬКО свойством "Content". Для каждой кнопки нужно брать значение для этого свойства из массива FileNames[].

Заранее сердечное спасибо!

Comment: `ItemsControl`, `DataTemplate`, `Binding`

Comment: мне не известно кол-во кнопок

Comment: Это ничего не меняет, вы просто ничего не изучили по выше указанным классам, иначе бы подобного не написали. Хотя бы вот https://stackoverflow.com/q/32457157/12888024

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/799373/220553